# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have been trying to solve this problem since some days so any help is welcome

When testing my React Native app with Jest, I get the following error with the [victory-native](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native) package:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

I visited many issues and questions which all seem to solve this problem by using the *[transformIgnorePatterns](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string)* key for the jest config

The problem is when i use that, I get another error :

`TypeError: Cannot set property '_currentElement' of undefined`

#### Jest config

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!react-native|victory-native)/"
  ]
},
```

#### Babel

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "env": {
    "test" : {
      "presets": ["react-native"],
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

RN Version: 0.46.2
Jest Version: ^20.0.4

Test command: `NODE_ENV=test jest --no-cache`

I am completely clueless about this now so any tips or hints would also do.

Thanks in advance!